# Selenium: unable to find a element in GWT App

Tags: javascript, perl, dom, selenium, gwt

i need to get the text/value from an Element in an GWT app. The app and the Element can be found here:

-open http://www.festo.com/cat/en-us_us/products

-click on "Products"

-click on "Software"

-click on "Rotary indexing table"

-click on "Next"

-click on "Next"*

Now you're on page "3. Load Settings"

-Enter 50 (kg cm²) as Mass moment of inertia

-Enter 50 (kg) as Mass

-Enter 50 (mm) as r for as Distance/Lever arm

-Enter 50 (deg) as greek letter theta

-Enter 50 (mm) as Z

-click next "Next"

Now your on page "4. Results"

Here you see the result for "C: total cycle time" (and other results) which will be 0.518 s for the values entered on the Page before.

I'm able to do all this automaticly  with selenium (in perl) till i reach page 4, here i can't grab the results. Can anyone give me an advice what to do? I guess it's not a perl problem.

If i use FireBug to get some more details, i also can't find the resulting value "0.518" in the HTML Tab. If i switch to the DOM Tab of FireBug i'm able to find it.

Thx

Roland

Comment: Can you paste HTML code which is related to your problem?

Comment: The field which contains the result **on the screen** is
<input class="GM53QT1CF GM53QT1CF-readonly" type="text" style="height: 26px; width: 98px;" readonly="">

Comment: Once give Thread.sleep() before closing browser. So that you can able to see the result. or else you can get the result from that page by using getText() and print it in log.

Comment: Use this xpath to get total cycle time input value:    ** html/body/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[1]/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/table/tbody/tr[1]/td/table/tbody/tr/td[1]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/div/table/tbody/tr/td[1]/input **

Comment: Wait/sleep made no difference, getText did not get the value. Addressing the field is not the problem, i belive, i wrote a highlight method, wich flashes this field without problems. So using the full xpath might not change anything.

Comment: which xpath have you used..can you post that xpath??

Comment: @SarithaG such hard coded xpaths are error prone and hard to maintain - it should be avoided

Comment: Then how did you called that element to get the result?

Comment: As I mentioned in my response - I was able to select it with class name input.GM53QT1CF

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GWT uses iframes - this is not friendly for Selenium tests. 
Your element is included in this iframe: `CamosIFramecamosFSV22E4A4C1E_EDC0_768B_CC78_8BA85ABADCCD`

You need to switch to the iframe first with something like:

```
driver.switchTo().frame("Your-frame-id");
```

When frames are generated dynamically, which can be the case here, you could try with passing index.

When you're on the correct frame you can try to find your element with css class: `input.GM53QT1CF` - but as I see it selects all input fields on the page. Selenium takes first one from the list, so in your case it should be ok.

Comment: My script switches to this IFrame directly after it clicked on "Rotary indexing table". Even switch to this fraim again on the results page makes no difference.
As i said, i can't see "0.518" or any of the other result values in the HTML Tab of FireBug, i can only see it in the DOM Tab.

Comment: I'm able to select this element with firebug - just selected firebug's 'inspect arrow' and pointed it on the element. Then I also could evaluate css selector with FirePath extension. Just had to select proper iframe. That are the only options I could use to verify your locators

Comment: If i use the "inspect arrow" an click on the field, i see this in the HTML Tab
`<input type="text" class="GM53QT1CF GM53QT1CF-readonly" style="height: 26px; width: 98px;" readonly="">`

Do i have to select the Frame in FireBug too? if yes, how?

Comment: Yes, that's ok. But FirePath https://addons.mozilla.org/pl/firefox/addon/firepath/ allows you to evaluate your locators on the page. On the left of its top menu you can chose desirable frame and check if it's fine.

Comment: Even in the FirePath Tab i dont see the resulting value if i click on it.

Comment: With Chrome using the developer tools, it's the same, i don't see the value

Comment: Ah, ok I see your point now. So I would try either as drkthng mentioned with pointing to the input field and copying its content to the clipboard. Or maybe with some direct JavaScript call.

Comment: PEBCAK - Problem exists between chair and Keyboard!!!

After trying to get this VALUE for days, i just noticed that the get_attribute('value') statement was disabled (commented). I guess i disabled it before i noticed yesterday to switch to this iFrame. afterwards i was so focused on FireBug that i missed it.

Thanks a lot siemic!

Comment: get_attribute('type'), get_attribute('title') and get_text() where still active

Answer (score 0):

You could try a combination of copying the input element's text to the clipboard via [ctrl + a] and then reading the clipboard, might be a workaround.

Make sure that you correctly locate your input element!

```
WebElement inputElement = driver.findElement(inputLocator);

//copy all text inside input element
inputElement.sendKeys(Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL, "a"));

//now read the clipboard
Clipboard clipboard = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard();
System.out.println(clipboard.getData(DataFlavor.stringFlavor));
```